# How do we cross reference to multiple items in Xtext?

Tags: xtext

I have a grammar which looks like below:

```
Module: MOD mid=ModId ;

Stmt: CALL nam=ModName ';';

ModName: (idn1=[ModId|ID] | ('"' idn2=[ModId|ID] '"') | (idn3=ID idn4=ID));
```

Basically, I have a statement where module name is mentioned. So when I try to call the module later, it should prompt me the module names defined (with or without quotes) and also allow me to enter a new variable name (which is not a module name) also.

How do I achieve this? I am able to achieve either referencing to the module name or defining a name, not both.

Example program:

```
Module add

Module subtract

Module divide

call add;    //referencing module name

call "subtract";  // referencing module name in quotes

call operation;   // without reference
```

Regards,

Anitha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple issues with that.

first for referencing with string have a look at https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2015/03/19/xtext-and-strings-as-cross-references/

For having an optional reference you have to change the grammar to have either a ID only or a Reference only. In the IDOnly case you could do something like

```
ModNameManipulator returns ModName: ref=[XXXX]
```

And then use IDerivedStateComputer and SyntheticLinkingSupport to create/populate the reference.

Or you adapt linking for no the throw errors.
Both of the solutions are not trivial and might need deeper Xtext knowledge

Comment: I can change the definition of the problem a bit to simplify it. Now in the call statement, it can either call a module name or a variable name. How do i cross reference two different types? I tried using scoping to achieve this, but still it shows only the first type (module name).

Comment: You need to inteoduce a super type MySupertype: A|B and reference that one

Comment: Thanks this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Christian. I was making a silly mistake by not assigning ModId to name. Now the content assist works fine.

The grammar looks like below now:

```
Module: 'MOD' mid=ModuleName;
ModuleName: name = identifier;

Var: d=DataType v=VarName;
VarName:  name=identifier;

Stmt:  'Call' ((idn1=[Names|ID] 'Mod.')| (idn3=[Names|ID] idn4=ID '.'));

Names: id = ModuleName| id2 = VarName;
```

I made changes in Scoping to merge lists to be able to provide both ModuleName and VarName for content assist. This works fine.

However once I enter the value, it throws error saying - "Couldn't resolve reference to Names"

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: can you give a complete reproducible grammar and sample model

Comment: Sorry. i could not get back on this earlier. But i was able to resolve the issue and i think it was not built correctly before.This is working now. Thanks for the help.